# How to upgrage joomla 2.5 to joomla 3.1.1

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have a joomla 2.5.9 and joomla 2.5.11

Because the easy of joomla 3, then I want to upgrade joomla 2.5.9 and joomla 2.5.11 of my own to joomla 3.11

Please tell me how to do that? thanks for your advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Joomla backend, when you first login, you will see a Quick Icon telling you whether Joomla is up to date or not. Click that button, then in the top right, click the "**Options**" button. Then in the drop down list, click on "**Short Term Support**", then "**Save and Close**".

It will then show you that there is an update available